# Is there an ehcache jsp tag?

Tags: java, jsp, ehcache, jsp-tags

In a current project of mine, JSPs are getting huge (lots of jstl end el logic, no Java), and due to increasing traffic, caching on many levels has become a necessity. Some components need to be dynamic, so we won't be able to use filter-based solutions. Unfortunately, the logic uses many custom tags and hardly ever uses includes, so [`SimplePageFragmentCachingFilter`](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/web-caching#SimplePageFragmentCachingFilter) won't help either.

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
<ehcache:cache key="${myApp.cacheKey}">
    <many />
    <jsp />
    <tags />
    <here />
</ehcache:cache>
```

This tag would expose a virtual writer for `pageContext.out` and flush that writer to the cache and the page and on subsequent requests would write directly from the cache to `pageContext.out`.

Does any such beast exist?

Hint: I know we should change the design, reduce logic in JSPs etc. Unfortunately, it won't happen. I'm not the one making decisions here, so please don't go there. Oh, and: yes, I have googled it.

Comment: I have seen such a mechanism used to cache the results of entire JSPs. But that was inside a proprietory content management system called CoreMedia.

Comment: @nfechner but was it a tag inside the JSP or was it a mechanism that cached he JSP invocation from the outside?

Comment: The second case. Caching the entire JSP. So I don't think that solution will help you.

Comment: @nfechner ok, that's roughly equivalent to the `SimplePageFragmentCachingFilter` I mentioned in the question, then

Comment: >Does any such beast exist? As OSCache is no more supported (its jsp tag did the trick), I think that the answer is unfortunatly NO. But I'm still searching for ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There existed two tag libraries for this: [Jakarta Cache](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/cache-doc/) and [OpenSymphony OSCache](http://www.opensymphony.com/oscache/). Both are retied and the Jakarta Cache library is nowhere available for download, but you can still download the OSCache library [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/opensymphony/oscache/2.4): [OSCache 2.4](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/opensymphony/oscache/2.4/oscache-2.4.jar).

It's supposed to be used as follows (after you just drop the JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` the usual way):

```html
<%@taglib prefix="oscache" uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/oscache" %>
...
<oscache:cache key="${myApp.cacheKey}">
    <many />
    <jsp />
    <tags />
    <here />
</oscache:cache>
```

Answer (score 3):

I made such a thing: https://github.com/psiegman/ehcachetag

Haven't used it on a production system yet, but it has decent code coverage.

Comment: Can you publish a maven artifact in a public repo? Even a snapshot release would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no, such a beast does not exist.

Comment: And I believe this should have been a comment.

Comment: Sean, usually I would make this a comment. But in this case, I'm quite sure that this is the correct answer to the question. The JSP mechanism for generating output almost certainly won't allow this concept.

Comment: Since you can write jsp output into a variable, there is nothing preventing such thing.

Answer (score 0):

There's an enhancement request open for this
http://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/CDV-1617
I recommend voting for it.